# Lost access to Mongo running on Google Cloud VM and can't ssh to it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a mongo instance running on a google cloud VM and my application lost access to it overnight. I'm not being able to SSH to it and Cloud console is looking weird.

VM Image: `bitnami-mongodb-3-2-1-1-r04-linux-debian-7-x86-64`

It first says I don't have permission to access the instance console page. Eventhough I'm the owner of the project and I can see it once I close the modal.

[image]

Then when I try to SSH using the built-in SSH tool I first get the following message. I see I have a VPC setup so I'm not really sure if that is actually expected or not.

[image]

If I try the alternative method I then get the following:

[image]

Does anyone has any hint on what could be the issue?

---

### UPDATE:

VPC Firewall settings are set to allow SSH and the target project is set for it this rule:

[image]

I also have an external static IP set for this VM.

Just yesterday I could connect to my mongo instance through port `27017` and it stoped working without touching any GPC configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have provided, it would seem that your GCE VM instance is currently utilizing IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy).

With this in mind, any overviewing the error message you are receiving, it would seem that your firewall rules aren't allowing connections on the SSH port. There should be an ingress rule to allow traffic to the instance on TCP port 22 (SSH) on that VPC network.

Generally, this is automatically created by GCP, on the default network it is typically called "default-allow-ssh", but you can also manually create it in the VPC Network -> Firewall rules tab. Make sure it applies to the instance in question (either through "All targets" or a target tag that matches the instance). You can read more about [GCP firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) in the documentation.

Likewise, make sure you have an external IP or that you are following one of the options [described here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances).

Comment: Hello Anthony, thanks for your answer. 
Just updated the question with further details. I have that all set, it just stoped working overnight. Is there any chance it is something on GCP side?

Comment: With the new insights you have given, I would suggest to try SHH-ing into the VM instance using the following [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) command, and provide us with the output:

gcloud compute ssh INSERT_VM_NAME \
--tunnel-through-iap \
--log-http \
--verbosity=debug